# Probability that an urn contains 3 balls after 20 draws - without replacement -

Tags: probability

Looks to me as a hard problem:

Let's say we have two urns $A$ and $B$. Initially, $A$ is empty and $B$ has $100$ balls.
At each draw, we randomnly choose a ball with equal chances **(among the whole set of balls) and we switch it to the other urn**.

1) At the end of 3 draws, what is the probability that A contains only one ball ?

2) At the end of 20 draws, what is the probability that A contains exactly 13 balls ?

**My way to see it:**

1) To have one ball in A after three draws, we have to have the following sequence: $P(BAB) = $ P(drawing the ball from A on the second draw) $= 1/100$.

because:

- First draw: we have no choice but to choose from B.
- Second draw: we have 1/100 probability to choose from A.
- Last draw: we have no choice but to choose from B.

**Do you agree ?**

2) We don't know the distribution of the random variable, so I tried to solve it using the expectations:

By having $X_i = +1$ if the urn A is getting one more ball and $X_i = -1$ if we remove a ball from $A$.

So, $E(X_i)=+1*p + (-1)*(1-p) = 2p-1 $.

What should be $p$ in this case ?

So $E(20X_i)=20E(X_i)= 20 (2p-1)$ ?

Is it the correct way to see it (through the expectation - I'm not so sure about this) ?
How can I deduct the distribution given that the draws are without replacement ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is less to the second problem than meets the eye. Note that if $k$ is odd, then after $k$ draws each urn has an odd number of balls, and if $k$ is even, then after $k$ draws each urn has an even number.

In particular, $13$ balls after $20$ draws is impossible.

Comment: For the second question, I tried to see it that way and I am tempted to say that the answer is 0 ? - Could we apply the hypergeometric distribution to that kind of problems ?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to have an odd number of balls in Urn A after $20$ draws: the probability is $0$.  Hypergeometric does not seem directly relevant to me. One could express the probability that after $k$ draws there are $q$ in Urn A as a complicated sum. But for our problem, *parity* considerations are enough.

Comment: But do you have a mathematical and general way to solve this kind of problem please ? Do you agree on my result for 1) ?

Comment: Your analysis of the first problem is correct.  As to general solution, it will be messy.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, many thanks. Yes, you're right, hypergeometric does not look suitable after thinking more about it.

Comment: You are welcome. *Parity* arguments (and fancier versions of parity) come up fairly often in combinatorics.

Comment: This is the Ehrenfest urn model (1907). It can be represented as a Markov chain.